# Handling `id` in derived Aeson FromJSON instances with Aeson/JSON

Tags: json, haskell, generics, aeson, custom-data-type

If I have `JSON` and I try to derive the `FromJSON` instances automatically with `Generics`, I run into problems with `id` existing in more than one place in the `JSON`.

Is there a way for me to override just the `id` part or do I have to write the whole instance in order to change those particular entries? The `JSON` actually has more fields, but I have left most of it out in this example. So it is actually rather tedious to write out the whole `FromJSON` instance.

JSON:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "brandId": 1,
      "productTypeId": 1,
      "identity": {
        "sku": "x",
        "barcode": "Ax"
      },
      "stock": {
        "stockTracked": false,
        "weight": {
          "magnitude": 0
        },
        "dimensions": {
          "length": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "volume": 0
        }
      },
      "financialDetails": {
        "taxable": false,
        "taxCode": {
          "id": 1,
          "code": "x"
        }
      },
... etc
  ]
}
```

CODE So far:

```
data Response = Response
    { response :: [Body]
    } deriving (Show,Generic)

data Body = Body
    { id                    :: Int
    , brandId               :: Int
    , productTypeId         :: Int
    , identity              :: Identity
    , productGroupId        :: Int
    , stock                 :: Stock
    , financialDetails      :: FinancialDetails
    } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data Identity = Identity
    { sku       :: String
    , ean       :: String
    , barcode   :: String
    } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data Stock = Stock
    { stockTracked  :: Bool
    , weight        :: Weight
    , dimensions    :: Dimensions
    } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data Weight = Weight
    { magnitude  :: Int
    } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data Dimensions = Dimensions
    { length :: Int
    , height :: Int
    , width  :: Int
    , volume :: Int
    } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data FinancialDetails = FinancialDetails
     { taxable :: Bool
     , taxCode :: TaxCode
     } deriving (Show,Generic)                  

data TaxCode = TaxCode
     { id      :: Int
     , code    :: String 
     } deriving (Show,Generic)                  


instance FromJSON Response
instance FromJSON Body
instance FromJSON Identity
instance FromJSON Stock
instance FromJSON Weight
instance FromJSON Dimensions
instance FromJSON FinancialDetails
```

This gives the error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( reponse.hs, interpreted )

response.hs:73:8:
    Multiple declarations of `id'
    Declared at: response.hs:19:7
                 response.hs:73:8
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Ideally I would like to change the first `id` to `body_id` and the second to `taxCode_id` without having to write out the whole instance.

Comment: The upcoming GHC 8.0 will have a DuplicateRecordFields extension https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields that will alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When deriving FromJSON instances you can pass an option to the `genericParseJSON` function. It's usually

```
data Foo = {- ... -} deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Foo where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions
    -- defaultOptions :: Options
```

while you can replace `defaultOptions` with an `Option` you constructed manually. The `Option` type have a field `fieldLabelModifier` that can preprocess the field name of your data type. You can define your data type as

```
data Body = Body
  { body_id :: Int
  ...
```

And write a helper function which maps `"body_id"` to `"id"` and anything else unchanged:

```
body_noprefix "body_id" = "id"
body_noprefix s = s
```

Then define the instance as

```
instance FromJSON Body where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON (defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = body_noprefix })
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could provide options for the generic instances.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you for your help!.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that GHC can't provide Generics, but that in Haskell record labels are also accessor functions and thus you get a name clash if you try to use the same label for two different records.

If you use the the functions from `Data.Aeson.TH` you can use `fieldLabelModifier` option to eg. remove prefixes from your labels.

```
data Identity = Identity
{ identitysku       :: String
, identityean       :: String
, identitybarcode   :: String
} deriving (Show)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions{fieldLabelModifier = drop (length "identity")} ''Identity)
```

This code requires the `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` pragma.

Answer (score 2):

Others have given great ways to modify the generated instances, which will sometimes be the best thing to do. It's not, however, your only choice. You also have the option of defining one or more of the types in separate modules, generating instances in those modules, and then importing the modules qualified or otherwise using qualified names to refer to the overlapping field names.